Should the RX and TX lines have the same length for an Ethernet PHY?
I have the ethernet PHY Realtek RTL8211F-CG and I wonder if the RX and TX lines should have the same length?

In my case, I have placed the TX and RX lines like this:


Likely duplicate of: What is the maximum recommended routing distance between MAC and PHY? The answer(s) explain relevant limitations, including maximum length and relative matching.

For RMII at 50MHz, no. The wavelength of 1/10th of a wave is ~12in so you would have to create a very big trace lenght difference to have the wave show up at a different time vs the clock.
For GMII at 125MHz, a 1/10th wavelength is 4.7in so still quite long and hard to misroute.
For Ethernet TX/RX you it is ~100MHz so roughly same wavelength for GMII.
I match them anyway because it's easy to do but that isn't necessary.
